# Sudoku Validator In C Using Threads Causing Segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, sudoku

I'm working on a Sudoku validator in C that uses a thread to check if the rows are valid, another thread to check the columns, and 9 threads to check each square. When I try to run my code I get a segmentation fault (core dumped).

I have the sudoku as a global constant 2D array that each thread accesses, and I am wondering if that is the problem?

based on the valgrind output it seems to have a problem with the thread function squares_check, and based on error checking outputs It stops working when it gets to the 6th square thread to create (8th overall of the 11 total)

The block of code it seems to get stuck at is:

```
while (i < THREAD_AMOUNT)
{
    if (pthread_create(&thread_ids[i], NULL, squares_check, &check_squares[square_count]) > 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR: pthread_create for square");
        exit(1);
    }
    i++;
    square_count++;
    printf("Square Check created\n");
}
```

i's value is 2 since I already did 2 pthread_creates already, one for the row thread and one for the column thread.

check squares is a 9 element array of the struct square, which has a row value and a column value. Row is the starting row of the square and column is the starting column of the square.

The code for the threads function squares_check is

```
void *squares_check(void *check_squares)
{
    struct square *current_square = (struct square*)check_squares;

    int start_column = (*current_square).column;
    int start_row = (*current_square).row;
    int end_column = start_column + 3;
    int end_row = start_row + 3;
    int i, j;
    int values[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    i = start_column;
    j = start_row;
    while (i < (end_column))
    {

        while (j < (end_row))
        {
            values[(sudoku[i][j])]++;
            j++;
        }
        j = start_row;
        i++;
    }

    if (values[1] != 1 || values[2] != 1 || values[3] != 1 || values[4] != 1 || values[5] != 1 || values[6] != 1 || values[7] != 1 || values[8] != 1 || values[9] != 1)
    {
        return (void *)1;
    }

    return (void *)0;
}
```

The output after running is

```
Making Threads
Row Check created
Columns Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If any other sections of code would help or if you want to see the Valgrind output let me know. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Ok, thanks to the comments I was able to make some progress and now all the threads are able to be created no problem. Now I am getting a segment fault after the 3rd thread is joined. my code for joining the threads is

```
while (i < THREAD_AMOUNT)
{
    if (pthread_join(thread_ids[i], &p_status) != 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR: Joining threads");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Threads may still be building their return, so lock stdout
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&output_lock) != 0)
    {
            perror("Could not lock output: ");
            exit(1);
    }

    if (i > 2)
    {
        valid[i] = *(int *)p_status;
    }

    if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&output_lock) != 0)
    {
            perror("Could not unlock output: ");
            return 5;
    }

    free(p_status);

    i++;
    printf("Thread Joined\n");  
}

i = 0;

if (valid[i++] == 1)
{
    printf("Rows aren't valid\n");
    is_valid = 1;
}

if (valid[i++] == 1)
{
    printf("Columns aren't valid\n");
}

square_count = 0;

while (i < THREAD_AMOUNT)
{
    if (valid[i++] == 1)
    {
        printf("The square starting at row: %d and column: %d is not valid.\n", check_squares[square_count].row, check_squares[square_count].column);
    }
    square_count++;
}

free(thread_ids);
```

my output now is:
    Making Threads
Row Check created
Columns Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Square Check created
Thread Joined
Thread Joined
Thread Joined
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It seems like the error is happening after the 3rd join, and the only thing that changes after the third join is that it enters the if loop. I'm assuming that there is some issue with how I am using the p_status (the return from the thread function)

Comment: posting a link to the complete source would probably help

Comment: Likely need to detect column/row wrap-around with `end_column = (start_column + 3)%9;` and adjust the `while()` loop to cope with that.  IOWs `sudoku[i][j]` is accessing outside indexes 0-8.

Comment: Thanks chux, I tried your solution out but it would extend the size of the last square (the one in position 6, 6) to not be checked as the end_column value would be lower than the actual value, but you led to realize my actual values I was setting were 1 too high. After changing that I am able to get to the part where I join the threads, but I get a segment fault now while joining. i'll edit the original post to match my new  problems.

Comment: p_status is probably null because you're not calling pthread_exit from your threads. Also your if condition should be if(i >= 2) if you are starting from i = 0

Comment: Thanks for the catch with the >=; I tried replacing my returns in my threads with pthread_exits (pthread_exit((int *) 1) when I return 1, pthread_exit(int *)  0) when I return 0 and pthread_exit(NULL)  when I dont want to return anything, but i still seem to be getting the same segmentation fault.

Comment: Why do you use threads?  If it is part of your assignment or for educational purposes, enjoy the complex world of multi-threading!  But if you are just looking for solutions, a brute force algorithm solves the problem in milliseconds.